# What's the necessity of $g'(x) \neq 0$ for all x in some interval in L'Hospital Rule

Tags: calculus

So I have here the statements of L'Hospital Rule from Apostol, Rudin and Spivak and they all have the following part:

" Suppose that $f'(x) ,g'(x)$ are differentiable on an open interval $(a,b)$ and that $g'(x) \neq0 \,\,\,\forall x$ in $(a,b)$..."

My question is: Why $g'$ must be different from $0$ for all $x$?

For me just needed to be different for some $x$. In my opinion let the function $H(x)=\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ the limit at $a$ only exist if $a$ is a limit point, so if if $g'(x)$ is a function like $(x-a)sin(\frac{1}{x-a})$ $a$ is a limit point even  not having any interval containing $a$ such that $g'(x) \neq 0 \forall x \,\,\,$in this interval

Comment: [Example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#Counterexamples_when_the_derivative_of_the_denominator_is_zero).

Comment: The obstruction is that you can't apply Cauchy’s mean value theorem, which is the key for proving L’Hôpital’s theorem. The counterexamples show that the obstruction cannot be removed.

Comment: Fact egreg, but can you show me a function whose derivative near a, takes 0 infinitelly? I can think in nothing